# Trigonometry Rate of Change Question

Tags: calculus

Here is the problem: A rotating light L is situated at sea 180 metres from the nearest point P on a straight shoreline. The light rotates through one revolution every 10 seconds. Show that the rate at which a ray of light moves along the shore at a point 300 metres from P is 136pi m/s.

I'm having some problems with this rate of change question. I'm not too sure where to really start. I thought to use the chain rule to solve this question. So far, I have dd/dt = dd/dr * dr/dt, where dr/dt is 0.1rev/sec. I'm not sure how to find dd/dr though. By using the circumference of a circle as d=2pir, differentiating this with respect to r, removes the r to make it d^1=2pi. This doesn't allow for the 180m or 300m information given to be included and gives the wrong answer. I also found this similar question at [Lighthouse problem: my answer does not match the key](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951595/lighthouse-problem-my-answer-does-not-match-the-key) , but I am struggling to apply the ideas here in this question to mine.

Any help on whether I am on the right track or how I should solve this question would be really useful. Thanks.

Comment: Your best starting point is a diagram showing which variables you want to define. Something like $r$ for the shortest distance from lighthouse to shore; $d$ for distance from that point to the point where the light hits the shore; $\theta$ for the obvious angle. You want $\frac{dd}{d\theta}$; you know  $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ and you can relate $d$ and $r$ and $\theta$ by trigonometry.

Comment: Indeed it would be good to draw a picture. I think you need to make a straight triangle, with the one length 180 and another one unknown. The angle is the angle that the lighthouse makes, so it's rotating at the given speed. And the question asks, when the hypotenuse length is 300 m, at what speed is the another side length of the triangle increasing?

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I tried what you both said and by drawing a triangle and labelling the necessary sides, I was able to find dd/dtheta and could solve the question from there. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x$ be the distance of the light ray along the shore from $P$ and $\theta$ be the corresponding acute angle between the light ray and $LP.$

We have that $$\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm d t}=\frac{2\pi}{10}=\frac\pi5;\\\tan\theta=\frac x{180};\\x=300\implies\theta=\arctan\frac{500}{300}=\arctan\frac53.$$

Thus, $$\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t}=\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d \theta}\times\frac{\mathrm d \theta}{\mathrm d t}\\
=180\sec^2\theta\times\frac\pi5.$$
At $x=300,$ $$\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t}=36\pi\sec^2\left(\arctan\frac53\right)\\
=36\pi\left(\frac{\sqrt{25+9}}3\right)^2\\
=136\pi.$$

Comment: Thank you very much, this working out makes a lot of sense and helps me understand how to solve this question much better. I really appreciate it :)